# Python. Не работает игра "Камень ножницы бумага"

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Написал програму, но есть некоторые моменты, которые мне непонятны.
В тех случаях, когда пользователь выбирает "Камень" или "Ножницы" - всё работает как надо, но как только вводит "Бумага" - програма независимо от выбора компьютера пишет "Что-то пошло не так". Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём конкретно может быть проблема? (Я новичок в Python, могу совершать глупые ошибки)

```
import random

number = random.randint(0,2)

arr = ["Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага"]

your_turn = input("Выбери, камень, ножницы или бумага: ")

computer_choise = arr[number]
print("Выбор комп'ютера: " + computer_choise)

if(your_turn != "Бумага" and your_turn != "Камень" and your_turn != "Ножницы"):
    print("Что-то пошло не так")
    exit()
elif(your_turn==str(computer_choise)):
    print("Ничья!")
elif(your_turn == "Камень" and computer_choise == "Ножницы"):
    print("Ты победил!")
elif(your_turn == "Камень" and computer_choise == "Бумага"):
    print("Ты проиграл...")
elif(your_turn == "Ножницы" and computer_choise == "Камень"):
    print("Ты проиграл...")
elif(your_turn == "Ножницы" and computer_choise == "Бумага"):
    print("Ты победил!")
elif(your_turn == "Бумага" and computer_choise == "Камень"):
    print("Ты победил!")
elif(your_turn == "Бумага" and computer_choise == "Ножницы"):
    print("Ты проиграл...")
```

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, у меня с бумагой всё работает. Вы точно вводите с большой буквы и без опечаток?

Comment: 100% ввожу всё правильно. Может быть, у меня проблема с самим редактором? Пишу код и компилирую я в Visual Studio Code

Comment: Окей, внезапно у меня всё заработало, хоть я ничего и не изменял. Странно всё это...

Answer (score 0):

Sanchez, привет! Попробуй так ;)

```
your_turn = input("Выбери, камень, ножницы или бумага: ").capitalize()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но программа уже сама по себе заработала. Спасибо)

Comment: видимо ты вводил слово с маленькой буквы вот проблема и возникала

Comment: Ни в коем случае, на этом этапе я детально проверял каждый шаг, всё вводил правильно. Единственное что я сделал - несколько раз перезапустил VSCode. Только после этого программа заработала как надо

Comment: ну окей. магия так магия :D